# zooming within a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating inside a main div, smaller divs from server side (each div contains data, text and images inside) [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0shW3.png)

I want to allow the user to zoom in or out (incase there are more divs then the screen width for example), in a way that the main div will stay with the same size and only the smaller divs will grow or shrink.

here's an example I've found
that provides the solution I want, but the difference is that:
1. I'm creating the div's during run time , and according to the data , the number of divs may change (the example present default image and div)
2. I want that ALL the divs will zoom in or out together.

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.vb" Inherits="TEST.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        var speed = 4;
        function showImage(src) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            with (div.style) {
                width = "300px";
                height = "300px";
                border = "2px solid black";
                textAlign = "center";
                overflow = "auto";
            }
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = src;
            img.width = 300;
            img.height = 300;
            div.appendChild(img);
        }

        function keydown(key) {
            var k = 0;
            if (key == 187) k = speed;
            if (key == 189) k = -speed;
            if (key != 0) {
                img.width = img.width + k;
                img.height = img.height + k;
                img.style.margin = ((300 - img.height) / 2).toString() + "px";

            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="keydown(event.keyCode)" onload="showImage('http://bjstlh.com/data/wallpapers/67/WDF_1122851.jpg')">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1>press (+) to zoom in <br /> press (-) to zoom out</h1>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not too familiar with Javascript - any help would be appreciated

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: What browsers are you targeting? Can you use CSS3?

Comment: using IE11 only